# How to get Tensorflow's batch_sequences_with_states to infer sequence lengths automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow's [tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states) to prepare data for an RNN, specifically batching and segmenting variable length sequences.

The code below is a toy example that I expect to run without error:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 10
STATE_SIZE = 5
STEP_SIZE = 20

input_key = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])

input_sequences = {
    "inputs": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]),
    "labels": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
}

input_context = {
    "length": tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
}

initial_states = {
    "cell": tf.zeros([STATE_SIZE], tf.float32)
}

# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states
batch = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
    input_key=input_key,
    input_sequences=input_sequences,
    input_context=input_context,
    input_length=None, # infer lengths
    initial_states=initial_states,
    num_unroll=STEP_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
```

I'm not feeding any actual data or running anything (other than to initialize the variables). All I am doing is starting the queue runner. I expect this example to run successfully (albeit not doing anything). However, when I run this an exception is thrown:

```
2017-08-08 01:06:00.789556: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.796772: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.798030: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.805150: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.810993: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.812120: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.818859: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.822800: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-08-08 01:06:00.823670: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
   [[Node: input_sequences_inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

My intention is to provide the `input_sequences` as a placeholder and provide the actual values during training. The sequences will be variable length and so I do not want to define a fixed size for this placeholder, hence the shape of `[None]` for `input_sequences["inputs"]` and `input_sequences["labels"]`.

The documentation suggests that you can provide `input_length=None` and lengths for the sequences in `input_sequences["inputs"]` will be inferred from the actual sequences:

> `input_length` is a Tensor scalar or an int recording the time dimension prior to padding. It should be between 0 and the time dimension. One reason we want to keep track of it is so that we can take it into consideration when computing the loss. If `pad=True` then `input_length` can be `None` and will be inferred.
>
> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Python 3.6.1, Tensorflow 1.2.1.

Comment: It does not answer this question, but one should not use queues and runners anymore. `tf.data` is a much cleaner, simpler, and mostly faster way to import data. This method https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch and pointers from there should help achieving your goal here.